# Cannot retrieve data with null values ​from columns

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have the data as below.

```
AccountNo,  PaymentCode, Priority
NULL,       01,          99
NULL,       01,          99
0711712916, 03,          99
0711712916, 03,          99
```

I want to get all the data above, I try to use the code below

```
 var prioritasPembayarans = db.VWPrioritasPembayarans.Where(x => arrValidPaymentCodes.Contains(x.PaymentCode))
                                                     .OrderBy(x => x.AccountNo)
                                                     .ThenBy(x => x.Priority)
                                                     .ToList();
```

class

```
public class VWPrioritasPembayaran
{
    [Key, Column(Order = 0)]
    public string AccountNo { get; set; }
    [Key, Column(Order = 1)]
    public string PaymentCode { get; set; }
    public byte Priority { get; set; }
    public decimal EndingBalance { get; set; }
    public decimal TotalTransfer { get; set; }
}
```

when I debug, I get 4 data,  [image: here's the screenshot]. 
In the third and fourth data I can expand and see the data, but in the first and second data I get a null value. 
what I want to ask is how to get the data like the third and fourth data even though the column *AccountNo* is null. thanks

Comment: Show VWPrioritasPembayaran class

Comment: Is `AccountNo` property non-nullable?

Comment: The null is a DBNull.Value.  So you can filer on AccountNo != DBNull.Value using a WHERE.

Comment: @trailmax `AccountNo` should be nullable since it's a string

Comment: I already edited my code @feihoa.

Comment: I added the `VWPrioritasPembayaran` class, and the `VWPrioritasPembayaranclass` was not a table but a view in SqlServer @trailmax

Answer (score 0):

A trick can be -

```
var prioritasPembayarans = db.VWPrioritasPembayarans.Where(x => arrValidPaymentCodes.Contains(x.PaymentCode))
                                                 .OrderBy(x => x.AccountNo != null ? x.AccountNo : "")
                                                 .ThenBy(x => x.Priority)
                                                 .ToList();
```

Comment: I need all the data, even though `AccountNo == null`,

Comment: @chaeusangchen try this query you will get all the data.